# Return the value of dictionary elment when key is exist

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I return the value of

```
dictionary <string, int >
```

element  when the  key is found for the first time???.

I'm trying the following code, but i'm sure I'm doing something wrong. because it takes long time ti return the value.

```
        private int GetIndex(string term)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var entry in dic)
        {

            var word = entry.Key;
            var wordFreq = entry.Value;

            if (word == term)

                index = wordFreq;

        }
        return index;
    }
```

Can some help please ?? thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just request it directly:

```
return dic[term]
```

That should do the trick!

But if you would like to return 0 when it doesnt exist, go this way:

```
int i;
if (dic.TryGetValue(term), out i)
    return i;
else
    return 0;
```

Comment: Both of your solutions are good for me. But i wonder why most of the programmers claim that we can't index the element of dictionary<string, int> !!!!

Comment: `Dictionary<>` is index by first Type so in your case it's string if you had `int,string` the int would be the index and just like an array [index] works

Comment: @Qaesar because the values in a dictionary are not ordered, and are not stored along each other, in contrary to `List` and arrays. `Dictionary` uses a data-structure called hash-table, in which the keys are looked up from the hash-value of the key. The order they end up in the hash-table could be totally different from the insertion order.

Comment: @Martin & Sina, in my case I have dictionary <string, int>. But when I run the program i see the dictionary is look likes <int,string, int> where, the first int is the index and the second int is the value that i have entered to the dictionary. So, what value will be returned ?? even the both int have the same order, but adding items to the  dictionary  may not be ordered every time!! can I have some explanations please ?? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dicitionaries are not meant to be used in a linear fashion and one does not index into them via a number. Each key is a unique hash value which when computed gives the internal location to be returned. Yes one can enumerate over a dictionary as you have, but that is not how a dictionary is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

[`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) has things defined for this already.  If you want it to throw an exception if the key is not found, use the [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx), e.g. `dic[term]`.  If you don't want it to throw, but instead get a `bool` saying whether it was found, use the [`TryGetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx), e.g.

```
int result;
if (dic.TryGetValue(term, out result))
    // do something
```